# Is there a way to prevent JPQL's FUNCTION from returning an object of type java.lang.Object?

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipselink, jpql, payara-micro

I have the following JPQL query running in a Payara Micro 5.2022.2 application.

```
TypedQuery<UserDto> query = entityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT new UserDto((FUNCTION('COALESCE', (select fullname from Person p where p.userId = u.id), 'Name not set'))) " + 
    " FROM User u WHERE u.id = :userId", User.class);
query.setParameter("userId", 12);
return query.getResultList();
```

The type of the field is returned as `java.lang.Object` and not as `java.lang.String` since the column, `fullname` is `varchar` in it's table.

This forces me to have the constructor to have an `Object` parameter and not `String`

I wanted to find out if there is a way to get this code `(FUNCTION('COALESCE', (select fullname from Person p where p.userId = u.id), 'Name not set')))` to return a `String` and not an `Object`

Comment: did I understand properly you are using `FUNCTION('COALESCE',...)` instead of built-in `COALESCE` in order to place scalar subquery there? have to tried  to enclose that into `cast(... as String)` or `str(...)`?

Comment: I was trying `cast(... as string)` all along and it was giving me this error `No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts`. I just tried it now and it now gave me this error `PSQLException: ERROR: type "string" does not exist`. Then I changed it to `cast(... as text)` to make it work.

Comment: sorry, I have missed you are on `eclipselink` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Andrey B. Panfilov's comment, I had to cast the return value to a String:

```
TypedQuery<UserDto> query = entityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT new UserDto(CAST(FUNCTION('COALESCE', (select fullname from Person p where p.userId = u.id), 'Name not set') as text)) " + 
    " FROM User u WHERE u.id = :userId", User.class);
query.setParameter("userId", 12);
return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: When the same war file was run in Payara Server 4.1 it worked as expected, there was no need to cast. So maybe there is a setting that I am missing.